# Getting Error 1022 on a mySQL select query

Tags: mysql

I have a simple table i am trying to run a select query on. I keep getting this error.
 #1022 - Can't write; duplicate key in table '/tmp/mysqltmp/#sql_120f_0'

Here is the table info
[image]

And this is the query im trying to run

```
SELECT COUNT( name ) , CONCAT( userapps.activity,  '/', userapps.class ) 
FROM userapps
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: that can't be a good sign... getting a dupe key error on a temp table that mysql itself has created to handle your query's results...

Comment: Have a look at http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=58081 Check your disk space and if there's plenty free then try to increase the size of the tmp_table.

Comment: Can you provide us with sample output of what you are after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird query; do you want:

```
  SELECT CONCAT(u.activity,'/',u.class) activity_class, COUNT(u.name) name_count
    FROM userapps u
GROUP BY activity_class
```